# Removing checkout steps sylius (adressing and shipping)

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, checkout, sylius

I know that a subject like this already exist, however after lot of tests the solution is not one for me.

This is my poblem :

I want to remove the first and the second steps of the checkout on Sylius (Adressing and Shipping). I made this code :

```
# app/Resources/SyliusShopBundle/config/routing/checkout.yml
sylius_shop_checkout_start:
    path: /
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment

sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment:
    path: /select-payment
    methods: [GET, PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
        _sylius:
            event: payment
            flash: false
            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:selectPayment.html.twig
            form: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Checkout\SelectPaymentType
            repository:
                method: findCartForSelectingPayment
                arguments:
                    - "expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart().getId()"
            state_machine:
                graph: sylius_order_checkout
                transition: select_payment

sylius_shop_checkout_complete:
    path: /complete
    methods: [GET, PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:completeAction
        _sylius:
            event: complete
            flash: false
            template: SyliusShopBundle:Checkout:complete.html.twig
            repository:
                method: find
                arguments:
                    - "expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart()"
            state_machine:
                graph: sylius_order_checkout
                transition: complete
            redirect:
                route: sylius_shop_order_pay
                parameters:
                    tokenValue: resource.tokenValue
            form:
                type: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Checkout\CompleteType
                options:
                    validation_groups: 'sylius_checkout_complete'
```

---

```
{# app/Resources/SyliusShopBundle/views/Checkout/_steps.html.twig #}

{% if active is not defined or active == 'select_payment' %}
    {% set steps = {'select_payment': 'active', 'complete': 'disabled'} %}
{% else %}
    {% set steps = {'select_payment': 'completed', 'complete': 'active'} %}
{% endif %}

{% set order_requires_payment = sylius_is_payment_required(order) %}

{% set steps_count = 'two' %}

<div class="ui {{ steps_count }} steps">
    <a class="{{ steps['select_payment'] }} step" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment') }}">
        <i class="payment icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">{{ 'sylius.ui.payment'|trans }}</div>
            <div class="description">{{ 'sylius.ui.choose_how_you_will_pay'|trans }}</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="{{ steps['complete'] }} step" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_checkout_complete') }}">
        <i class="checkered flag icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">{{ 'sylius.ui.complete'|trans }}</div>
            <div class="description">{{ 'sylius.ui.review_and_confirm_your_order'|trans }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#app/config/config.yml

sylius_shop:
checkout_resolver:
    pattern: /checkout/.+
    route_map:
        cart:
            route: sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment
        payment_selected:
            route: sylius_shop_checkout_complete
```

---

```
#app/Resources/SyliusCoreBundle/config/app/state_machine/sylius_order_checkout.yml

winzou_state_machine:
    sylius_order_checkout:
        class: "%sylius.model.order.class%"
        property_path: checkoutState
        graph: sylius_order_checkout
        state_machine_class: "%sylius.state_machine.class%"
        states:
            cart: ~
            payment_skipped: ~
            payment_selected: ~
            completed: ~
        transitions:
            select_payment:
                from: [cart, payment_selected]
                to: payment_selected
            complete:
                from: [payment_selected]
                to: completed
        callbacks:
            after:
                sylius_process_cart:
                    on: ["select_payment"]
                    do: ["@sylius.order_processing.order_processor", "process"]
                    args: ["object"]
                sylius_create_order:
                    on: ["complete"]
                    do: ["@sm.callback.cascade_transition", "apply"]
                    args: ["object", "event", "'create'", "'sylius_order'"]
                sylius_save_checkout_completion_date:
                    on: ["complete"]
                    do: ["object", "completeCheckout"]
                    args: ["object"]
```

---

```
{# app/Resources/SyliusShopBundle/views/Checkout/SelectPayment/_navigation.html.twig #}

{% set enabled = order.payments|length %}

<div class="ui two column grid">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="{{ path('sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment') }}" class="ui large icon labeled button"><i class="arrow left icon"></i> {{ 'sylius.ui.change_address'|trans }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right aligned column">
        <button type="submit" id="next-step" class="ui large primary icon labeled{% if not enabled %} disabled{% endif %} button">
            <i class="arrow right icon"></i>
            {{ 'sylius.ui.next'|trans }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my issue :

> The controller for URI "/en_US/checkout/complete" is not callable. Expected method "completeAction" on class "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\OrderController", did you mean "deleteAction"?

Thanks for your time